# bash function not exiting

Tags: bash, conda

I have tried some suggestions I saw on similar posts, but my script is not exiting after it completes. I have to hit enter for it to exit. Its running a function called foo, and its running okay. But when it finishes its just writing Done $i where i is the last item, and then just space, I have to hit enter to exit. Thank you in advance.

```
#!/bin/bash

PATH=/opt/conda/bin:$PATH
export PATH


eval "$(conda shell.bash hook)"
conda activate prokka_env &&

foo () {
    local i=$1
    prokka $i --outdir ./"${i%.*}" --prefix "${i%.*}"
    echo Done $i
}

for i in *.fasta; do foo "$i" & done
```

Comment: What does the `&&` at the end of the line do?

Comment: Why is there `&&` at the end of the `conda activate` line?

Comment: And are you intentionally submitting each `foo "$i"` instance as a background process?

Comment: Because it runs everything in the background, I think your script exits before any of the `Done $i` messages are printed, and the reason you think you need to hit enter is just that the prompt scrolled up already when the `Done $i` messages get printed. To confirm this theory, run your script an try typing `ls<enter>` right then. If the command actually runs, you'll know your script had properly ended already.

Comment: I have removed the && and am testing it again now. yes i am intentionally submitting each foo $i instance as a background process. They are independent processes and want to speed up the processing time

Comment: A hint: Use quotes like `local i="$1"` and for each `"$i"`. Otherwise you script is broken for files like `a b.fasta`.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, I assume you meant to use `&` after `conda activate prokka_env` instead of `&&` (though it may be better to not run that command in the background).

Secondly, since you run all your `foo`s in the background with `&`, you need to add `wait` at the end of your script so that your script will end automatically once all background tasks have finished running.

For more info on `wait` see its entry in the [GNU bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Builtins.html#Job-Control-Builtins) or run `help wait`.

Comment: I think `&` at the end of conda activate would be a bad idea - the environment should be loaded before any work starts. Otherwise good answer, `wait` is the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, adding wait did the trick. This is the final code in case someone else finds it useful.

```
#!/bin/bash

PATH=/opt/conda/bin:$PATH
export PATH


eval "$(conda shell.bash hook)"
conda activate prokka_env

foo () {
    local i=$1
    prokka $i --outdir ./"${i%.*}" --prefix "${i%.*}"
echo Done $i
}

for i in *.fasta; do foo "$i" & done
wait
echo "All jobs completed."
```

Comment: FYI, if you have `conda init bash` configured, then adding an `-l` flag to the shebang (`#!/bin/bash -l`) would make it so you could delete the lines above `conda activate`.

Answer (score 0):

I think what's really happening is:

- script runs
- script **exits**
- you're presented with the command prompt
- **then** the `echo Done $i` is sent to stdout and appears to overwrite the command prompt while leaving the cursor sitting on a new line (sans any command prompt)

In this scenario the script **has** exited and you're left sitting at the command prompt, but the delayed output from the background job makes it look like your program is still running.

Consider:

```
$ foo () { sleep 3; echo 'Done'; }

$ foo &
$                               # immediately provided with command prompt
```

Three seconds later the terminal looks like:

```
$ foo &
$ Done                          # the 'Done' is added to the line and ...
                                # cursor is left sitting on blank line
```

At this point you're still at the command prompt ... it just doesn't look like it.  From here you could run a command, eg:

```
$ foo &
$ Done
date
Fri Sep 24 12:28:05 CDT 2021
$
```

Or just hit `<return>` to get a new command prompt, eg:

```
$ foo &
$ Done
                                # hit <return>
$
```

As other have pointed out, `wait` will keep the script from exiting until all background jobs have completed.